# html tags issue in php print

Tags: php, html, decode

I have description developed in tinymce.Here are tags like `<br/>`, `<p>` etc etc.i want to print it to show its functionality.It shows me as same as it is.

Here is output

```
<p><strong>Partial Sea and Marina view, Fully Furnished 2 bedroom apartment available for rent in Bahar 1, JBR!<br /></strong><br />
```

I want strong and p tag to make strong and paragraph.here is my code

```
$dess = str_replace("&nbsp;", '',$row['description_demo']);
$dess = str_replace("nbsp;", '',$dess);
echo htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$dess)));
```

Comment: I thing, you need to `$dess=str_replace("&lt;","<", $dess);` and `$dess=str_replace("&gt;", ">", $dess);` for that

Comment: Could you explain "i want to print it to show its functionality"?

Comment: tags to be interpreted as HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `htmlspecialchars()` will disable all HTML tags. You say that you want the `<strong>` and `<p>` tags to be interpreted as HTML but if you're using `htmlspecialchars()` they will necessarily be converted to `&lt;strong&gt;` and `&lt;p&gt;` which will make the browser to actually display the text "`<strong>`" and "`<p>`" as simple text rather than interpreted HTML tags.

What you're trying to do seems more like allowing some HTML tags while removing the others. To do that you shouldn't use regex. Instead, you need to use an HTML parser like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Here is how you would use it in your example:

```
// Include the HTMLPurifier library
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault(); // Set default configuration
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'p,strong,br'); // List your allowed HTML tags
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config); // Init HTML Purifier with the above setting

$clean_description = $purifier->purify($row['description_demo']); // Purify the HTML from TinyMCE

echo $clean_description; // Check that the output is what you want
```

Cheers